# Using revtex on Ubuntu 14.04 (texlive-publishers installed)

Tags: 14.04, apt, latex

I'm trying to compile a LaTeX document with the `revtex` package, but I get a compiling error stating "File ŕevtex4.sty'not found". Here's what I've tried so far with no success, based on my own digging and common internet solutions:

- Installing `texlive-publishers`; apt says it's already installed (and reinstalling is no help);
- Replacing `revtex4` with `revtex4-1` or `revtex`; those other *.sty files are also not found;
- Running `sudo texhash`;
- Changing engines (I've tried PdsLaTeX, LatexMk, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX);
- Using different editors.

BTW, `texlive-extras` and `texlive-full` are also installed. Running `apt show texlive-publishers` I see the latter package has no breakage or conflict problem with the others.

---

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

In my machine, I get the log below.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the top your file? It should load `revtex4.cls` and not `.sty` --- unless it is a very, very old document using a legacy LaTeX.

Comment: @Rmano, sure, I've added an MWE as well as my LaTeXila log. I've just started writing this article, so I guess I'm not depending on anything legacy. Let me know if I can provide any other info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me (Ubuntu 16.04, TeXLive 2015) if I change the snippet into:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

It outputs a warning:

```
Class revtex4 Warning: No Society specified, using generic APS style.
```

So probably it needs some options to tailor it for the journal. You can see the documentation with

```
texdoc revtex
```

(if `texdoc` doesn't work, search for a file named `aipguide4-1.pdf`in your system)

[image: second page of the docs]

So for example for *Journal of Applied Physics* you should use:

```
\documentclass[aip,jap]{revtex4-1}
```

Comment: That works for me too! Dropping the `article` class and using `revtex` feels weird, but I hope there are no bigger consequences than what I've faced so far (`title`, `author`, etc. had to be placed *after* `\begin{document}`, and biblatex stopped working).

Comment: Probably the class wants to use `bibtex` - it seems it has built-in bibliography formats. Happy to help!